# Sci-fi/paranormal TV show from the 90s to 2000s - Female investigator

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, science-fiction, fantasy

I'm trying to find out the name of an older TV show I watched when I was a kid. It was a supernatural/sci-fi TV show, and involved a widowed (I believe) mother with her young teenaged daughter.

The mother was a detective of supernatural occurrences if I remember correctly. Her daughter became friends with a teenaged brunette named Miranda (I think), who didn't have any parents, and was found to be a witch.

The mother eventually told her daughter to stop seeing Miranda due to the fact that Miranda tended to get her into trouble and sometimes dangerous situations.

**EDIT:** It had a more serious tone than So *Weird*. Miranda was in multiple episodes, if not most of the series. The daughter was somewhat rebellious and hung out with Miranda frequently.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like [Poltergeist: The Legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poltergeist:_The_Legacy). It ran in the late 90s on Showtime and the Sci Fi Channel. It was about a team of paranormal investigators and one of them was Dr. Rachel Corrigan, a widow with a daughter called Kat who had a friend  called Miranda in season 4 (when Kat was a teenager); she appeared for several episodes and tried to get Kat into witchcraft. In one episode, for instance:

> Rachel catches Kat casting a "fun" spell and reprimands her, but Kat's continuing witchcraft practice and friendship with Miranda turns into serious trouble.

Clips are scarce, I'm afraid, but here are pics of [Rachel](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-jSV6IRcotGk/Vcj-k6SGPGI/AAAAAAAAWOQ/qh3N4_14_Y0/s1600/poltergeist%2Bthe%2Blegacy%2Bs1_rachel.JPG), daughter [Kat](http://www.childstarlets.com/lobby/bios/portraits/alexandra_purvis12.jpg) and friend [Miranda](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjEzNDM1ODE4OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTM5MzIyMjE@._V1_UY317_CR104,0,214,317_AL_.jpg).

Comment: This is it! I couldn't remember it for the life of me, but this is it. I did find that videos and clips are widely unavailable, but I could tell by your description and the images that this is the show I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @Brekke No problem! Don't forget to approve the answer by clicking on the check mark next to it, this effectively resolves the question. And welcome to M&TV! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a swing with "So Weird" (1999-2001)

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0169247/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/So_Weird

Specifically, season one starts off as "...with Fiona Phillips on tour with her famous rocker mother Molly, brother Jack, a skeptic, bus driver Ned, his wife Irene, and their son Clu. Stringing together all of Fi's paranormal encounters was her search to communicate with her father, who died when she was three years old."  Fiona apparently discovers throughout the series that she is (part) witch.

Episode 8 of season 1 is "Strangeling" which includes a cousin named Miranda; the cousin's mother is playing a witch in Macbeth.

https://thiswastv.com/2012/09/06/review-so-weird-angel-and-strangeling/

Comment: Thank you for answering, but that isn't it. It had a more serious tone to it.  Miranda was in multiple episodes, if not most of the series. The daughter was somewhat rebellious and hung out with Miranda frequently. I can't remember much but little bits and pieces of episodes.